# jupyter throwing error: socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I run a pyspark cluster on AWS EMR and use Jupyter to the pyspark driver. Recently, the script failed. Jupiter fails to start a server. I install with `conda install jupyter` and start with `sudo initctl start jupyter`. The cluster runs fine. Here are the config values of the server.

```
# jupyter configs
mkdir -p ~/.jupyter
touch ls ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
HASHED_PASSWORD=$(python -c "from notebook.auth import passwd; 
print(passwd('$JUPYTER_PASSWORD'))")
echo "c.NotebookApp.password = u'$HASHED_PASSWORD'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/mnt/$BUCKET/$FOLDER'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "c.ContentsManager.checkpoints_kwargs = {'root_dir': '.checkpoints'}" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "c.NotebookApp.port = 8080" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I found that after the update to jupyter 5.7. I had to modify the config parameters. Change

```
echo "c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

to

```
echo "c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Comment: it helped me, thanks
when launching like this I got the same error:
jupyter-notebook --open_browser=False --ip=*

I changed it to this line and everything started working fine: 
jupyter-notebook --open_browser=False --ip="0.0.0.0"

Comment: @VladimirGorovoy glad it helped!

Comment: FWIW this is the relevant issue where this was changed: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/3714