# Can't start Jupyter lab in Linux

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to start Jupyter lab in linux box, but its throwing following error

> socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

I tried to completely research on this, but couldn't resolve this.

It used to work until last week

Command I am using:

```
jupyter lab --port 6095
```

Error I got:

```
(vigenv) [vxp1gwa@goxsd5107 pynotebooks]$ jupyter lab --port 6095
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'allow_remote_access'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 864, in _default_allow_remote
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip)
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/bin/jupyter-lab", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1628, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 353, in init_webapp
    super().init_webapp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1378, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 159, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 252, in init_settings
    allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 867, in _default_allow_remote
    for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/opt/data/anaconda/Anaconda/envs/vigenv/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Have you looked at this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706238/jupyter-throwing-error-socket-gaierror-errno-2-name-or-service-not-known

Comment: error looks similar to this issue: [https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/718](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/718#issuecomment-423462368), check your config as mentioned in the link in above comment

Comment: Thanks much Poojan and Davedwards. The solution worked!! Thanks much!!!