# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name of service not known

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter

I have been following the steps below to install Jupyter in AWS EC2: https://chrisalbon.com/aws/basics/run_project_jupyter_on_amazon_ec2/

I created the config file and gave 8888 as port. I then launched `jupyter notebook` to check how the installation went and I receive the bellow error:

> socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name of service not known

[image]

I will add that I am already currently running a RStudio session on this instance on a 8787 port.

I assume this is not impacting what I am trying to do (install jupyter notebook) but just wanted to point it out in case of.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This post actually solved my issue:

[jupyter throwing error: socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706238/jupyter-throwing-error-socket-gaierror-errno-2-name-or-service-not-known)

Sorry didn't find when searching for info on SO.